# hook document.createElement script to change src

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to hook `document.createElement` to change the `src` property value for each assignment.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
var original = document.createElement;
    document.createElement = function (tag) {
      var element = original.call(document, tag);
      if (tag.toLowerCase() === 'script') {
        Object.defineProperty(element.__proto__, 'src', {
          set: function(newValue) {
            element['src'] = 'test';
          }
        });
      }
      return element;
    };
```

The problem with this is that `element['src'] = 'test';` is calling the `setter` again and again causing stack overflow.
I've tried different approach where I save a local variable outside and set its value to `newValue` and add a `getter` to the `src` property that returns it instead.
The problem with this approach is that if the script element is later appended to the dom, then an script tag with not `src` attribute is added, like the append method is somehow trying to get the `src` property in a different way then accessing it normally so the `getter` is not called and so I'm left with an empty script tag.

What can I do in this situation, any thoughts on how I can make it so I could 'replace' the value intended to use with the `src` attribute of scripts with another value?

EDIT:
This is the hook I ended up with:

```
    Object.defineProperty(HTMLScriptElement.prototype, 'src', {
  set: function(newValue) {
    const r = /(?:[^:]+:)?\\/\\//;
    if (r.test(newValue)) {
      this.setAttribute("src", 'http://localhost:8080/v1/proxy?url=' + (newValue.startsWith('http') ? encodeURIComponent(newValue) : encodeURIComponent('http:' + newValue)));
    } else {
      this.setAttribute("src", 'http://localhost:8080/v1/proxy?url=' + encodeURIComponent(absolute('${originalHost}', newValue)));
    }
  }
});
```

I realized I need to cover all possible ways of changes `src` attributes of `script` element including `setAttribute('src', '...')`
If I were to hook `setAttribute` I would cause a stack overflow since I already hooked the `src` property `setter` and used `setAttribute` inside it.
How can I achieve hooking `setAttribute` as-well in-order to have full control of what the `src` value is without causing a stackoverflow?

Comment: Monkeying around with DOM methods is generally a Bad Idea(tm). You *could* try using `element.setAttribute("src", "test")`, but that could very well trigger the same loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really bad practice to mess with methods and prototypes you didn't create, but here might be your solution anyway.

Simply replace "`element['src'] = 'test';`" with "`element.setAttribute('src', 'test');`". That way you can avoid using the property. The `setAttribute` method interacts with the element's attributes directly rather than through the browser's attribute getters.

Comment: Again though, this is really bad practice!

Comment: Thanks, it worked.
I know it's bad practice but I'm trying to achieve something I don't think can be achieved otherwise.
I wish to intercept all async loaded scripts to redirect them to a proxy of mine. I've tried a static approach of analysing all assignments of a script file (even obfuscated ones) but it just have too many edge cases that can't be solved without evaluating some of the code which eliminates that purpose of static analysis (say someone use simple encryption like xor to resolve a variable to 'src' and then use it to assign a value).
If you have a better idea I'm all ears. :)

Comment: I think it would be significantly more practical just to have a setter for `HTMLScriptElement.prototype.src`, rather than reassigning the `document.createElement` function and doing what you're doing now. It's still bad practice, since you'd still be messing with prototypes, but it would be a little less sloppy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I would do that, and again gotta work with what I got no better solution I guess :)

Comment: I've updated the question, I need a solution to hook `setAttribute` as-well, if you have something in-mind I would appreciate any help.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this. You'd store `Element.prototype.setAttribute` into another property on `Element.prototype` and then overwrite it. Inside your version, do what you want, and then call the original. I'm not going to provide code that shows exactly how to do this because it's really bad practice outside of debugging, as is everything else here you're doing.